# How to obtain the thread status of 1 MVC controller in another

Tags: c#-4.0, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a mobile website using `jquery` `mobile+` `MVC4.net`. There are 3 separate modules with their own individual views and controllers.

In one module I call a service which generates PDF reports; this process takes approx 5 min so I show a status indicator and remove the indicator once I get a response. This all works well and it doesn't hang the UI, user can navigate and do operations.

The problem comes when user navigates to another module. I don't know how I can get the status of the thread which is in running state when it is moved to another controller as the thread will be lost if I move to other View/Controller.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bit Micky Mouse but clearly there is a need. Two possible options:

1. Maintain your thread model but instead have the monitoring thread
   send updates to a database and then have your client occasionally
   check the database.
2. Consider a solution that utalizes SignalR. The
       reporting thread could notify the client.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: Thanks Andleer..can there be any other alternatives like using Web service notification or WCF Polling duplex...learning Signal-R at this point will be bit difficult due to less time.